# SQL Server Reporting Services Web Portal Login Permissions

Tags: reporting-services, permissions

I need to control who can log into the SQL server web portal.

I'm running SSRS 2016.

I tried going to Site Settings > Security and removing all users/groups listed and adding just my windows account as an admin, but other people can still login without any problems. I googled around but I can't seem to find anything. Most of the sites I go to tell me to do what I've already done.

I need to be able to lock it down to just a couple people that can log into the server, and only one account that can deploy the solution.

(We've been having problems with people creating their own RDL's uploading them and using them instead of using the solution which is in SVN).

Comment: Have you looked to see if the group or domain has been given privileges?  Also remember that there's 2 places it needs to be changed. In security and in the folder itself. - Under site security and under manage folder

Comment: Well, when you navigate to the url for the web portal you get a pop up to enter your login info...I just want to restrict people from being able to log in to the site as a whole. Wouldn't that just be under site security?

Answer (score 1):

Just change the security of all folders and all site settings to only allow YOUR user. That way even if they get on the site they will have no access to any folders.

Comment: There's no way to keep them from logging in completely?

Comment: I ended up doing this. It works, but I would still like to be able to restrict the login itself.